# PHP Move Files With Specific Format vs Move All Files

Tags: php

I have these files in /public_html/ directory :

```
0832.php
1481.php
2853.php
3471.php
index.php
```

and I want to move all those **XXXX.php** (always in 4 digits format) to directory /tmp/, except index.php. how to do it with reg-ex and loop?

Alternatively, how about moving all files (including index.php) first to /tmp/ then later on put only index.php back to /public_html/, which one you think is less CPU consuming?

Last thing, I found this tutorial to move file using PHP: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/04/php-copying-renaming-and-moving-a-file.html

But how to move ALL files in a directory?

Comment: what do you mean by BASH question? I don't get it...

Comment: Do you have to move it using PHP only? If that is one time, you could move using shell, like bash.

Comment: since my code is PHP, sure I want to move it using PHP.

Comment: If CPU consumption is what you're worried about then, yes, using bash is the better option, from within a PHP script you can do this using `proc_open`, `system`, `exec` and the like. Other than that, as ever: what have you tried

Comment: you can loop thru the directory via `while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))` and use `if else` statement to move accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to do it directly via the file system, but if you absolutely have to do it with PHP, something like this should do what you want - you'll have to change the paths so that they are correct, obviously. Note that this assumes that there could be other files in the public_html directory, and so it only get the filenames with 4 numbers.

```
$d = dir("public_html");

while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    if($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') continue;
    if(preg_match("@^\d{4}$@", basename($entry, ".php")) {
        // move the file
        rename("public_html/".$entry, "/tmp/".$entry));
    }
}

$d->close();
```

Comment: bro, your Reg-Ex here : @^\d{4}$@ only to validate 4 digits, right? but I just realize that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FilesystemIterator` with `RegexIterator`

```
$source = "FULL PATH TO public_html";
$destination = "FULL PATH TO public_html/tmp";

$di = new FilesystemIterator($source, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$regex = new RegexIterator($di, '/\d{4}\.php$/i');

foreach ( $regex as $file ) {
    rename($file, $destination . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->getFileName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are in fact overkill for this, as we only need to do some simple string matching:

```
$dir = 'the_directory/';

$handle = opendir($dir) or die("Problem opening the directory");

while ($filename = readdir($handle) !== false)
{
    //if ($filename != 'index.php' && substr($filename, -3) == '.php')
    //   I originally thought you only wanted to move php files, but upon
    //    rereading I think it's not what you really want
    //    If you don't want to move non-php files, use the line above,
    //    otherwise the line below
    if ($filename != 'index.php')
    {
        rename($dir . $filename, '/tmp/' . $filename);
    }
}
```

Then for the question:

> alternatively, how about moving all files (including index.php) first to /tmp/ then later on put only index.php back to /public_html/, which one you think is less CPU consuming?

It could be done, and it would probably be slightly easier on your CPU. However, there are several reasons why this doesn't matter. First off, you're already doing this in a very inefficient way by doing it through PHP, so you shouldn't really be looking at the strain this puts on your CPU at this point unless you are willing to do it outside PHP. Secondly, that would cause more disk access (especially if the source and destination directory aren't on the same disk or partition) and disk access is much, much slower than your CPU.

Comment: I got this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function open_dir() in /home/xxxx/public_html/test.php on line 4. the files need to be moved actually stored in public_html/web/, I tried to use $dir = 'web'; and $dir = '/web' or $dir = '/web/'. all of them generates same error. does my PHP not support open_dir function?

Comment: @RobertHanson: Sorry, my mistake. It's `opendir`, not `open_dir`

Answer (score 1):

in fact - I went to [readdir manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) page and the fist comment to read is:

```
loop through folders and sub folders with option to remove specific files. 

<?php 
function listFolderFiles($dir,$exclude){ 
    $ffs = scandir($dir); 
    echo '<ul class="ulli">'; 
    foreach($ffs as $ff){ 
        if(is_array($exclude) and !in_array($ff,$exclude)){ 
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){ 
            if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){ 
            echo '<li><a href="edit_page.php?path='.ltrim($dir.'/'.$ff,'./').'">'.$ff.'</a>'; 
            } else { 
            echo '<li>'.$ff;    
            } 
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff,$exclude); 
            echo '</li>'; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    echo '</ul>'; 
} 

listFolderFiles('.',array('index.php','edit_page.php')); 
?>
```